# The thing I am?

Tags: riddle

When heard I mean two things

Take away my second letter I become a color

Take away my second and third letter I can be traveled on

Take away my first and last letter and I'm left with a twin

What am I?

Comment: Damnit. This is gonna bug me all day.

Comment: A normal color (red, blue, etc.) or a weird color?

Comment: Uuugh I've just gone through every homophone removing the second letters and I didn't find a color. Then I did the same for the colours and didn't find something you could travel on. This is tricky

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Same here. The only homophones I found which fit the color requirement are the following: choral, reed, rued, whine... But they obviously don't fit any other... I used [this list](http://homophonelist.com/homophones-list/) of homophones and [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colors_(compact)) of colors... Either I made a funny mistake in my code or I give up :P These are the longest lists I found...

Comment: The thing I am? Hard to find! What am I? Tricky!

Comment: What does "I'm left with a twin" usually mean in these kind of puzzles? Is is a palindrome word? Is it a word like "xyzxyz" made of two equal parts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you a

> Reed?

When heard I mean two things

> When heard, you can mean **to read** or you could also mean **a [reed](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed_(plant))**

Take away my second letter I become a color

> Removing the second letter leaves us with **red**

Take away my second and third letter I can be traveled on

> Removing the second and third letters leave us with [**RD**, which is the name of a Travel Agency](http://www.rdtravellimited.com)

Take away my first and last letter and I'm left with a twin

> Removing the first and last letters leave us with **EE**, which is a set of twin letters.

Comment: Well... If this is the correct solution, I should've googled RD before giving up, lol... :D

Comment: I was about to leave a hint, because I just saw the comments and saw that @LukasRotter had acctualy said the answer!  Yes I am a reed!  To simplify I would have also accepted that, rd. Is also short for road.